# VStudio 2008 - find and replace window is hidden behind code window

Tags: visual-studio-2008

This could be a trivial question for many
I am working in VStudio 2008 - 
The find and replace window is hidden behind code window. If I press hotkeys CTRL+F I am able to search but still the find window is not visible

How do I bring the find and replace window to the foreground?

Comment: How do you know it is hidden behind a window?  Could be off the screen too.

Comment: I am able to search the text and once I click the enter button, the first match is highlighted
This means the find window is still running but behing the code window isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the Menu:

View | Find Results | Find Results 1

Comment: I would need to see the "find" window not the results one